# Why does inner_join from dplyr change the data type of column?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I am trying to use `inner_join` to perform an SQL inner join
on two data frames in R.
One of the columns of my data frame is of the data type `chron`.
Unfortunately, the result of the `inner_join`
has the data type of the column changed into `num`.
Why is this happening?

#### MWE

```
require(chron)
require(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(name = c('Alice', 'Bob'),
                  id = 1:2)
print(str(df1))
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name: Factor w/ 2 levels "Alice","Bob": 1 2
#  $ id  : int  1 2

df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                  birth_chron = as.chron(c('2010-01-01 00:11:22',
                                           '2010-01-01 00:11:22')))
print(df2)
#   id         birth_chron
# 1  1 (01/01/10 00:11:22)
# 2  2 (01/01/10 00:11:22)
print(str(df2))
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ id         : int  1 2
#  $ birth_chron:Classes 'chron', 'dates', 'times'  atomic [1:2] 14610 14610
#   .. ..- attr(*, "format")= Named chr [1:2] "m/d/y" "h:m:s"
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "dates" "times"
#   .. ..- attr(*, "origin")= Named num [1:3] 1 1 1970
#   .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "month" "day" "year"

result <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'id')
print(str(result))
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ name       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Alice","Bob": 1 2
#  $ id         : int  1 2
#  $ birth_chron: num  14610 14610
print(result)
#    name id birth_chron
# 1 Alice  1    14610.01
# 2   Bob  2    14610.01
```

**Response to comment**
I am using dplyr version 0.4.1.

Comment: What's your `dplyr` version? This was a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/819) that sounds like it was fixed version 0.4. or 0.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/641) github issue, I would surmise that they simply haven't built support for **chron** columns, at least not yet.